# How to remove the outliers from a dataset?

Tags: r

I　have a dataset containing noise points. How can I remove lower and upper 1% data points using R?

Comment: Big lag in small comment: it is best in general not to interpret outliers as meaning just (fractions of) highest and lowest data points. There are many other (and usually better) ways to deal with outliers. See threads tagged as such on Cross Validated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to do something in R.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how many points. If it's hundreds or maybe a few thousand or so, the easiest way would be to sort the data and omit the first and last [n/100] points.

If it's a lot of points, you use O(n) quantile selection algorithms to identify the required quantiles and then omit the points outside them.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can use either *conditional indexing* or `subset()` function. See basic examples here: http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html. It is not totally clear, though, what exactly do you mean by "lower and upper 1% of data points" *criterion*. The "by value" criterion doesn't make sense, as these data points would not be considered outliers. So, I **assume** that the criterion meant is "by number" of data points. For that, you would need to have some code along the following lines (obviously, where `myData` is a data frame):

```
mySize <- nrow(myData)
cutoffPercent <- 1  # adjust cutoff value, as needed
lowerLimit <- cutoffPercent * (mySize / 100) + 1
upperLimit <- mySize - lowerLimit
newData <- myData[lowerLimit:upperLimit, ]
```